# Reading and storing names in an array from user input

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm currently in the midst of creating a program that takes in 10 names from user input, stores them in an array and then prints them out in upper case. I know there's been similar threads/questions asked but none of them really helped me. As per, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadAndStoreNames {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //take 10 string values from user
    System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");
    String n = scan.nextLine();


    String [] names = {n};
    //store the names in an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    //sequentially print the names and upperCase them
    for (String i : names){
        System.out.println(i.toUpperCase());
        }

    scan.close();

}

}
```

The current error I'm getting is this (after only 3 inputs I may add):

```
Enter 10 names: 
Tom
Steve
Phil
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at ReadAndStoreNames.main(ReadAndStoreNames.java:22)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
String [] names = {n};
```

The size of `names` is now 1, with the value 10.
What you want is:

```
String [] names = new String[n];
```

The latter is the correct syntax for specifying `size` of arrays.

EDIT:

It seems like you want to read `n` using the scanner. `nextLine` can be anything, so not just an integer. I would change the code to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadAndStoreNames {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many names would you like to enter?")
    int n = scan.nextInt(); //Ensures you take an integer
    System.out.println("Enter the " + n + " names: ");

    String [] names = new String[n];
    //store the names in an array
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    //sequentially print the names and upperCase them
    for (String i : names){
        System.out.println(i.toUpperCase());
        }

    scan.close();

}

}
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to properly finish scanning input

Comment: have tried specifying the array as you say but I get a squiggly red line under the n in ".. = new String[n];" with the message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int"

Would I have to parse the string to an int or something similar? My programming skills leave much to be desired I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, thanks very much mate :) and so I can return the favour slightly; you're = you are. When talking about anything belonging to somebody else, your is the correct word.

Comment: Haha you grammar nazi! I rushed the answer a bit, but I know the difference don't worry:P

Comment: Admittedly yeah I am but it's only because it's my native tongue :D